# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder' to custom ITemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, custom-controls

When you create a ListView, there is a property on the control that allows you to specify the ID of the PlaceHolder in the LayoutTemplate that is used to hold the controls for each item.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvTest" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="testPlaceholder">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="testPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I am trying to create a custom templated server control but would like to have a property on the template itself as I expect to have several different templates. My extremely simplified, trivial example is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ControlLibrary
{
    [ParseChildren(true)]
    public class TestContainer : Control, INamingContainer
    {
        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
        [TemplateContainer(typeof(TestContainer))]
        public TestTemplate TestTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

            DataBind();
        }

        public override void DataBind()
        {
            base.DataBind();

            CreateChildControls();
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            Controls.Clear();

            var phTest = new PlaceHolder();
            phTest.ID = "phTest";

            Controls.Add(phTest);

            if (this.TestTemplate != null)
                this.TestTemplate.InstantiateIn(phTest);

            this.ChildControlsCreated = true;
        }
    }

    public class TestTemplate : ITemplate
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
        {
            container.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(this.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I add the template to my .aspx file like below I get an error saying **CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder' to 'ControlLibrary.TestTemplate'**

```
<CustomControls:TestContainer ID="testContainer" runat="server">
    <TestTemplate>
        test
    </TestTemplate>
</CustomControls:TestContainer>
```

Is it possible to do this or will I have to put all configurable properties on the parent container itself?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did everything correctly except the template property declaration. Any template must be declared as `System.Web.UI.ITemplate`. Just replace your template declaration with:

```
public ITemplate TestTemplate { get; set; }
```

And it should start working. For reference see [How to: Create Templated ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/36574bf6(v=vs.100).aspx).

To do a trick with custom attributes for template you need to add one more class inheriting from collection:

```
public class TestTemplateList : List<TestTemplate> { }
```

And change declaration of the control as following:

```
[ParseChildren(true, DefaultProperty = "TestTemplates")]
public class TestContainer : Control, INamingContainer
{
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public TestTemplateList TestTemplates { get; set; }

    // ... OnLoad and DataBind left intact

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Controls.Clear();

        var phTest = new PlaceHolder();
        phTest.ID = "phTest";

        Controls.Add(phTest);

        if (this.TestTemplates != null)
        {
            foreach (var testTemplate in TestTemplates)
            {
                ((ITemplate)testTemplate).InstantiateIn(phTest);    
            }
        }

        this.ChildControlsCreated = true;
    }
}
```

After that you should be able to declare control in both ways. You can skip specifying `TestTemplates` because it is declared as a `DefaulProperty` in `ParseChildrenAttribute`:

```
<CustomControls:TestContainer runat="server" ID="testContainer">
    <CustomControls:TestTemplate Name="test">
    </CustomControls:TestTemplate>
</CustomControls:TestContainer>

<%-- OR --%>

<CustomControls:TestContainer runat="server" ID="wc11">
    <TestTemplates>
        <CustomControls:TestTemplate Name="test">
        </CustomControls:TestTemplate>
    </TestTemplates>
</CustomControls:TestContainer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Changing the property type to ITemplate allows the page to load without error, but I'm still unsure how to add a property to the template itself. Is this possible? For example, I would like to have <TestTemplate Name="test"> instead of <TestTemplate>.

Comment: @JKasper11 I have updated my answer. You need to do a little trick with default container for `TestTemplate`.